# Can't include cordova.js file in android Cordova app with ReactJS ES6

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've been developing android cordova app with ReactJS ES6 and until now I had cordova.js script commented out in my index.html.

Everything was working like a charm, but when I try to include my bundled js alongside with cordova.js, app does nothing except for displaying black screen forever.

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried to pack bundle.js either with and without webpack production flag, but it seems to have no effect.

I could leave cordova.js file excluded but as far as I know this script is necessary to fire events like 'deviceready' and use cordova plugins.

Since I want to use some plugins in the future, I have to do something about this.

What could be a cause ?
How to properly mount my main React component to DOM, being sure that cordova is ready ?

I tried in main.js for webpack:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App.jsx';


document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
},false);
```

... and couple of other tries.

When I run adb logcat it says:

```
    I/chromium( 3312): [INFO:CONSOLE(839)] "Uncaught Invariant Violation:     Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {define, require, version, platformVersion, platformId, addWindowEventHandler, addStickyDocumentEventHandler, addDocumentEventHandler, removeWindowEventHandler, removeDocumentEventHandler, getOriginalHandlers, fireDocumentEvent, fireWindowEvent, callbackId, callbacks, callbackStatus, callbackSuccess, callbackError, callbackFromNative, addConstructor}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `App`.", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/bundle.js (839)
```

I found these addDocumentEventHandler etc. in cordova.js file.
How to make it not collide with my bundle.js ?

Comment: Problem solved. All I had to do was prepend window to document like so in main.js for webpack:

    window.document.addEventListener('deviceready', () =>   ReactDOM.render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'))
 , false);